# Fastest way to build an index (list of substrings with lines of occurrence) of a String?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

### Problem:

Essentially, my goal is to build an ArrayList of IndexEntry objects from a text file. An IndexEntry has the following fields: String **word**, representing this unique word in the text file, and ArrayList **numsList**, a list containing the lines of the text file in which **word** occurs.

The ArrayList I build must keep the IndexEntries sorted so that their **word** fields are in alphabetical order. However, I want to do this in the fastest way possible. Currently, I visit each word as it appears in the text file and use binary search to determine if an IndexEntry for that word already exists in order to add the current line number to its **numsList**. In the case of an IndexEntry not existing I create a new one in the appropriate spot in order to maintain alphabetical order.

### Example:

_

One

Two

One

Three

_

Would yield an ArrayList of IndexEntries whose output as a String (in the order of **word**, **numsList**) is:

One [1, 5], Three [7], Two [3]

Keep in mind that I am working with much larger text files, with many occurrences of the same word.

### Question:

Is binary search the fastest way to approach this problem? I am still a novice at programming in Java, and am curious about searching algorithms that might perform better in this scenario or the relative time complexity of using a Hash Table when compared with my current solution.

Comment: try to use `Map` instead of `List` in the first place. It will give the constant time lookup performance. After build the map then convert that into your desire list.

Comment: Java already has a class for that. You want a `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a TreeMap or a ConcurrentSkipListMap which will keep your index sorted.

However, if you only need a sorted list at the end of your indexing, good old HashMap<String, List> is the way to go (ArrayList as value is probably a safe bet as well)
When you are done, get the values of the map and sort them once by key.

Should be good enough for a couple hundred megabytes of text files.

If you are on Java 8, use the neat `computeIfAbsent` and `computeIfPresent` methods.

Comment: all of this can be optimized until the cows come home, but as always: measure first, then optimize